# nested loops through the names of excel sheets using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code which looks in a folder and copies all files ending with **DAT** in Sheets.

[image]

After that I want to check if the date occurring in `Worksheets("Input").Range("X2")`

[image]

is the same as in the name of a sheet then I will check for IDs occurring in 
`Worksheets("Input").Range("c2")`  and match with the same **ID** in the name of one of  sheets with the correct date. To begin with this part I started with

```
' for the exact match
Dim mRange  As Range
Set mRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("X2")
Set mRange = Range(dicRange, dicRange.End(xlDown))

Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer

         ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
         ' workbook.
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         ' Begin the loop.
        For Each direc In mRange
          For I = 1 To WS_Count
            If direc & "K1LTIOS1.DAT" = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Nam Then
            ' Insert your code here.
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
                MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name
(what I want to do actually : copy the whole line from the sheet 
ddMMYYK1LOS1.DAT where the ID from Worksheets("Input").Range("c2")` occurs )
        End If
                 Next I
                Next
```

But I get an error message in  `If direc & "K1LTIOS1.DAT" = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Nam Then`: **run time error '438'**!

1) what is the reason of this error?

2) probably  this kind of nested loops is not so efficient!? Is there any better possibility?

Comment: Where is your ***End If*** ??

Comment: you are missing `End if` for this statement `If direc & "K1LTIOS1.DAT" = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Nam Then`

Comment: oh you are right, sorry! but what about an alternative method? Do you know another method nested nested loops

Comment: You should use [Smart Indenter](https://www.add-ins.com/macro-products-for-Microsoft-Excel/how-to-indent-vba-code/how-to-indent-vba-code.htm) it'll save you a lot of time reformatting and you'll catch issues like this becuase the indentions will be off.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I've heard that before but it works for me.  [Screenshot of my System](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wysu37u14bmheug/MySystem.png?dl=0) I must be missing something. I'm I somehow running Excel 2016 & VBA7 in 32bit mode on a 64bit CPU with Windows 10?

Comment: @ThomasInzina It's the bitness of the host application that matters - 32-bit Office is a 32-bit host process, that's why an add-in built with VB6 can work.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm using Office 365.  I thought that PtrSafe and LongPtr were not available to 32bit systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any indication from your code what `direc` is. Where do you `DIM` it, and what is it Dimmed as? But this is your real problem:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Nam
```

What is the `.Nam` property/method?

Comment: you are totally right. There is no indication true even if I check via ? in the console.

Comment: Actually, I'm kind of an idiot. Since you are using it in a `For Each` loop, it must be a variant. And since you do `Dim` mRange, it will be a cell. I would recommend explicitly dimming it as variant however. Adding `Option Explicit` at the top of all your code modules will help enforce this and ultimately lead to better code.

Comment: ok I did not know that one can dim the cell (in this case direc). However still one question: how can I implement this part: copy the whole line from the sheet 
ddMMYYK1LOS1.DAT where the ID from Worksheets("Input").Range("c2")` occurs in Worksheets("Input").Range("Y2")